# Object overriding with stacks (Java)

Tags: java, object, stack

I'm trying to write a code that displays all the cards in a deck. Unfortunately, the last card added to the stack seems to keep overriding all the previous entered cards. How can I prevent this from happening? Right now when I enter the code, it simply displays the line "Ace of Spades" 52 times.

```
import java.util.*;

public class cardSearcher{

public static void main(String[] args){
 Stack<card> deck = new Stack<card>();
 String[] value = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King","Ace"};
 String[] suit = {"Diamonds","Hearts","Clubs","Spades"};

for (int i=0;i<value.length;i++){
  for (int j=0;j<suit.length;j++){
        deck.push(new card(value[i],suit[j]));
  }
}

while (!deck.empty()){
  card chosenCard = deck.pop();
  System.out.println(chosenCard.value +" of "+ chosenCard.suit);
  }
 }
}
```

Here's the card code:

```
public class card {

    public static String value = "";
    public static String suit = "";

    public card(String valueofCard, String suitofCard) {
        card.value = valueofCard;
        card.suit = suitofCard;
    }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question, where's the `card` implementation?

Comment: Please use standard Java conventions and name classes starting with uppercase letters.

Comment: seems it's the problem of your `Card` class, and yes, you should use uppercase for classnames

Comment: This works fine for me with a trivial `card` class declaration.

Comment: Not a stupid question. 50 rep says `suit` and `value` are `static`. ;-)

Comment: Here's the card code:public class card{
  
  public static String value="";
  public static String suit="";
  
  public card(String valueofCard, String suitofCard){
    card.value =valueofCard;
    card.suit = suitofCard;
  }
  
}

Comment: @user2019594 Please edit your original question and add it there instead of trying to paste it into a comment.

Comment: @chrylis Good call! :)

Comment: don't use static for `value` and `suit`

Answer (score 7):

Variables that are `static` belong to the class as a whole, not to any instance. When you're modifying those, you're modifying variables that are shared among all of the instances. Remove the `static` modifiers on the variables to make them individualized to each instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **static** when declare the variables for value and suit.

You can declare these values using **private String value; private String suit;** and **generated the getter/setter.**

Doing this, you can get the expected result.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class cardSearcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack<card> deck = new Stack<card>();
        String[] value = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };
        String[] suit = { "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Clubs", "Spades" };

        for (int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
                deck.push(new card(value[i], suit[j]));
            }
        }

        while (!deck.empty()) {
            card chosenCard = deck.pop();
            System.out.println(chosenCard.getValue() + " of "
                    + chosenCard.getSuit());
        }
    }
}

class card {
    private String value;

    private String suit;

    /**
     * @param value
     * @param suit
     */
    public card(String value, String suit) {
        this.value = value;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    /**
     * @return the value
     */
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * @param value
     *            the value to set
     */
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    /**
     * @return the suit
     */
    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    /**
     * @param suit
     *            the suit to set
     */
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you mean to say "You should *NOT* use static."?